# How to generate code from XML?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I'm new to Android and have been struggling with custom views. I'm wondering if there's any way I can generate code from an XML so that I can simply paste it in to my custom view class, create whatever functions I need, and then dispense with the XML file, instead of losing sleep over inflation, attribute sets, and Xml pullers.

Comment: If you are new to Android, why are you fussing with custom views? If more than 5% of Android developers ever implement an Android `View` class in their life, I'd be stunned. Even for those who do, it's a fairly advanced topic, not something that I would advise for somebody new to the platform.

Comment: Because I've been given fairly tricky project to do and the other solutions I can identify are equally difficult. Being able to paste in the code generated from an XML would really make life easier.

Comment: "Because I've been given fairly tricky project to do and the other solutions I can identify are equally difficult" -- that is rather unlikely. "Being able to paste in the code generated from an XML would really make life easier" -- there is no "code generated from an XML" with respect to layout inflation, any more than there is "code generated from an HTML" in a Web browser or "code generated from a `.XSLX`" in Microsoft Excel. Layout inflation creates an object model; it does not generate source code.

Comment: If the answer is you can't get code from an XML (sure about that?), why didn't you just give a straight answer instead sounding all defensive?

Comment: "sure about that?" -- it's certainly not part of Android. I can't rule out somebody having written a tool for it, but I have not encountered one in eight years. "why didn't you just give a straight answer" -- I upvoted the "straight answer" you already received. According to you, you are "new to Android", and so I decided to try to determine why you are going down an unusual path for anyone, let alone a newcomer.

Comment: Often times when it comes to exploring other options, its important to ask why to know if its WORTH going down such a unusual path. And we use that question to curbside ideas that are rather obtuse. You should really listen to experience and standards to ensure you don't waste your time. @T.Everson

Comment: But it's not "obtuse". It's a perfectly natural question. In other visual editors, e.g. with Swing, I am quite used to obtaining a Java representation of my GUI design. Anyway, I've finally managed to get an answer of sorts. Thanks for the help, everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Inflation is generating code, or rather real objects, from an XML. It reads your XML and produces a view hierarchy that will be used to display the UI.

You definitely want to stick to XML layouts. I know it feels strange. When I first saw them, my first thought was "OMG, not XML". But it turns out, it is actually a well thought system and using XML defined layouts makes you more productive.

**EDIT:**

If you need to do some additional work in your custom View after it gets inflated, you override [`onFinishInflate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onFinishInflate()).

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I will stick with XML, but in this case the hybrid I desire is slightly convoluted. I can't merely inflate the XML as I want to add functionality to the class. So is there a way of actually looking at the code corresponding to an XML layout, or with Android do you always have to do it the roundabout way?